# Handling nested data arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, nested

I'm stuck...
I want to use data from a field in a nested array. I'm newbie so I missing some parts :-(
If a write in debug `d[0].children[1].birthdate` I get a correct value. When I try to plot my date I only get the first child from my "parent" data.

```
   //Part of my code:

    circle.append("circle") 
    .style("fill", "purple")
    .attr("r", 5)
    //This get me each parent first child but I need all the children e.g Adam, Eve, Julia....
    .attr("cx", function(d,i,j) { return x(new Date(d.parent[j].birthdate));})
```

My Data:

```
"parent":[
     "name": "Mum",
       "children": [
            {
                "name": "Adam",
                "birthdate": "2013-01-05"
            },
            {
                "name": "Eve",
                "birthdate": "2013-02-05"
            },
            {
                "name": "Julia",
                "birthdate": "2013-03-05"
            }
        ]
    },        
    {
        "name": "Dad",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Romeo",
                "birthdate": "2013-04-05"
            },
            {
                "name": "Maria",
                "birthdate": "2013-03-15"
            }
        ]
    },
    "name": "StepMom",
       "children": [
            {
                "name": "A",
                "birthdate": "2013-01-05"
            },
            {
                "name": "B",
                "birthdate": "2013-02-05"
            },
            {
                "name": "C",
                "birthdate": "2013-03-05"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but in your code you don't have `.children`. That is, instead of

```
.attr("cx", function(d,i,j) { return x(new Date(d.parent[j].birthdate));})
```

you probably want

```
.attr("cx", function(d,i,j) { return x(new Date(d.children[j].birthdate));})
```

On a different note, you should parse your dates properly instead of relying on the browser to do so:

```
.attr("cx", function(d,i,j) { return x(d3.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse(d.children[j].birthdate));})
```

Comment: Hi Lars 
Thank's for your quick answer. I tried that one with children earlier but that did not help me :-(. I still just get the first child in each parent.

I know this is not the correct syntax but if I could write something like:
d.parent[i].child[j].birthdate 
would give me the correct answer. I had appended my data with my whole data that I read from my json file
    .data(tasks);

Comment: Hi I managed to solve the problem by doing: 

    var circleGroups = svg.selectAll('g.main')
        .data(parent)
 .enter()
 .append('g')
 .classed('main', true);

    circleGroups.selectAll('g.sub')
        .data(function(d) { return d.birthdate; })
 .enter()
 .append('circle')
 .classed('sub', true)

This a problem I worked with before. I now do a box with the parent and with in that box I plot the children.

Thanks for taking your time to help me.

Maria